# unittest, running test from other file

Tags: python, unit-testing

I can't seem to get the Test1.test_something() in test2 to work.. not sure if it's because they are both inheriting from the same base?

Helper.py:

```
class baseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self, param="Something"):
        print param
        pass
```

Test1.py

```
from Helper import baseTest

class test1(baseTest):

    def setUp(self):
        super(test1, self).setUp('foo')        

    def test_something(self):
        assert 1 == 1, "One does not equal one."
```

Test2.py

```
from Helper import baseTest
import Test1

class test2(baseTest):

    def setUp(self):
        super(test2, self).setUp('bar')

    def test_something(self):
        Test1.test_somehing()
```

Now, I had this working previously, when I had the setUp for test1 and test2 within their classes, but once I had them both inherit from baseTest, I started getting a `unbound method <method> must be called with Test instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't just call `Test1.test_something()` since `test_something` is an instance method, not a class method. Your best bet is to have `test2(Test1.test1)` so that you can directly inherit this test method and no need to recreate it if you don't have the use case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Test1.test_something()` is an instance method, not a class method. So you can't just call it like that (besides, even if it is class method, it should have been `Test1.test1.test_something`).

One way to do it (without messing around with the `unittest.TestCase` mechanism):

`Test2.py`

```
import Test1

class test2(Test1.test1):
    # whatever else
```

And you're done, `test2` inherits `Test1.test1.test_something()` automatically. If you need your `test2`'s `test_something` to do extra stuff, just do `super(test2, self).test_something()` within your overridden definition of `test_something` in `test2` class.

Answer (score 0):

Move the tests that are shared by both `Test1` and `Test2` classes into `BaseTest`:

test.py:

```
import unittest
import sys

class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self, param="Something"):
        print param
        pass
    def test_something(self):
        assert 1 == 1, "One does not equal one."    

class Test1(BaseTest):
    def setUp(self):
        super(Test1, self).setUp('foo')
```

test2.py:

```
import test
import unittest
import sys

class Test2(test.BaseTest):
    def setUp(self):
        super(Test2, self).setUp('bar')
```